# OSX Fuerte Install Python Error Msg

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, wxwidgets, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following "http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/OSX/Homebrew", installed "numpy nose" and running "cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/fuerte -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF":

CMake Warning at build/cmake/rosunit/rosunit-extras.cmake:17 (message):
add_pyunit() is deprecated.  For Python tests, use add_nostests() instead.

and further down:

CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.7/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:91 (MESSAGE):   Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_FOUND)

is it necessary to also install gdal? And if so from where?

Suggestions to fix?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33574/osx-fuerte-install-python-error-msg/) by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2012-05-08

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-05-08**:
Yes, I got the python warnings too ... they aren't an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try these [instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source) ... I think the ones you are following are a little out dated. These worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on 2012-05-08**:
Followed your instructions to 1.3.1 Layer 1 with Ok completion until running both Debian & non-Debian  DCMAKE commands-not sure which one. Same result "CMake error at rx/tools/CMakeLists.txt.wx-enhanced swig binary not found. Aborting"

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-05-09**:
OSX is not Debian (linux) so use the the not Debian option. Did you install swig??

**Comment by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on 2012-05-09**:
I did not explicitly. Did that install get missed in the scripts? What package should I use?

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-05-09**:
It looks like ros/fuerte/swig-wx is broken (I don't know ruby, so I can't debug it): swig-wx.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting '<' or '
' or ';'